# What is the name of the category of t apartments built-60 centimeters below the ground floor?

Tags: word-choice

Like the word **penthouse**, do the apartments built -60 centimeters below the ground floor have a particular name?

Comment: What is special about 60 cm as opposed to 30 cm or 90 cm? Housing terminology is very localized, and will vary by country and region.

Comment: basement apartments, lots of them in NY, for example. Don't about about the 60 centimeter thing.

Comment: Are the apartment's occupants gnomes?  60 centimeters below the ground floor, that's an apartment less than two-feet high.  Only newborn babies could walk around in that-- if newborn babies could walk.

Comment: @Nancy the 60 cm might be the height of the ceiling about ground level, to allow space for windows. A habitable basement is rarely fully below ground level. The ground floor then has a few steps up to its door.

Comment: Bezad Falahati. Do you mean that the floor of the basement apartment is 60 centimetres below _ground level_ which suggests that the floor of the ground floor apartment is around 2 metres above ground level. In my experience most basement apartments are set deeper than this, more like a metre to a metre and a half at least.

Comment: BoldBen. The explanation Weather Vane offered is exactly what I meant by a -60 meter basement apartment. In fact, they are 60 centimeters below the courtyard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One such term is *garden-level apartment*.

> A garden-level apartment is considered to be generally situated between a basement and first floor, so that people standing up inside it would find their heads at or around street level.

[*How Stuff Words*](https://home.howstuffworks.com/real-estate/buying-home/what-do-you-need-to-know-about-buying-a-garden-level-property.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for

***[basement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/basement)***

> a part of a building consisting of rooms that are partly or completely below the level of the ground:
>
> - Our kitchenware department is in the basement.
> - a basement flat

(Cambridge Dictionary)